# getting source of website using https , with cURL

Tags: curl

i want to get website HTML code. 
the code i am using is

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  int written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
  return written;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl_handle;
  static const char *headerfilename = "head.txt";
  FILE *headerfile;
  static const char *bodyfilename = "body.txt";
  FILE *bodyfile;

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

          curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.chess.com");

          curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);

  curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);

  headerfile = fopen(headerfilename,"w");
  if (headerfile == NULL) {
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    return -1;
  }
  bodyfile = fopen(bodyfilename,"w");
  if (bodyfile == NULL) {
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
    return -1;
  }
   curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,   CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, headerfile);

  curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
            fclose(headerfile);

  curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
      return 0;
}
```

this code works for google (which uses http ) , but not for chess.com (which uses https).
how can i get it to work for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the curl code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: I think doing this without careful consideration first is a downright counterproductive advice and opens this user for MITM attacks and more.

Comment: Hi @DanielStenberg, thank you for pointing that, what would you advise instead ?